# Radar doesn't fit the div properly, cutting off some of the contents. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, css-grid, amcharts, radar-chart

I am using amcharts and I have a grid layout on my page to store 3 elements: List, map and radar chart.

The radar chart doesn't display properly for some reason. It doesn't matter what dimensions and sizes I give to the parent div, it doesn't display the radar with all the labels. It always cuts off some of them.

I couldn't find anything about it in documentation or in here. Here are the results of my stylings: [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bYE.png), [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf5Yf.png) [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5USSM.png).

Comment: In Chrome you can go into developer mode and inspect the element in question - and in the CSS pane you can see all the elements that it inherits from - and selectively enable/disable or tweak them, for leads... have you tried this?

Comment: I gave it a try. I've put the "overflow: visible" style property in every element that library have built, but it didn't display the radar fully even that way. Library builds the radar in svg so I assume there are some settings to am4core or the chart itself that I could apply to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unsuccessful attempts at altering CSS, I fixed it by adding a title of the chart at the top and label with opacity 0 at the bottom using charts prototypes in JS. I couldn't find any solution in documentation, but to set fixed maxHeight of the radar in pixels. The solution with pixels wouldn't work well with CSS-Grid.

[fixed container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VElSU.png)